# Computing a third order tensor efficiently in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tensor

If `x` denotes a `d` dimensional column vector and `e_i` denotes the `i`th standard basis in the Euclidean space `R^d`, I would like to compute the following third-order tensor in python in an efficient way:

[image]

Here, the circled-cross refers to the tensor outer product. For now I have been relying on the following rather inefficient code:

```
import numpy as np
from sktensor import ktensor,dtensor

d=5
x= np.random.normal(0,1,(d,1))

z= np.zeros((d,1))
I= np.identity(d)

T1= ktensor([x,x,x])
T2= ktensor([z,z,z])
T3= ktensor([z,z,z])
T4= ktensor([z,z,z])

for j in range(d):
    T2 = T2+ ktensor([I(:,j),I(:,j),x]
    T3 = T3+ ktensor([I(:,j),x,I(:,j)]
    T4 = T4+ ktensor([x,I(:,j),I(:,j)]

T= T1-T2-T3-T4
```

Comment: I'd suggest moving away from `sktensor` for a start, seems poorly maintained (I can't seem to get it running to compare). You could write this in pure `numpy` or maybe have a look at `tensorflow`.

Comment: @ncfirth: What would be the implementation of this quantity in numpy?

Comment: I'll write an answer in numpy, but I can't test whether it's faster as I can't install sktensor.

Comment: @ncfirth: It's possible to install sktensor in Ubuntu. Windows I am not sure. You need a distribution called nose and afterwards it's straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numpy` based answer as request by OP's comment. Not tested against `sktensor`

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(42)
d = 5
x = np.random.normal(0,1, size=(d,1))
I = np.identity(d)

ans = np.outer(x, np.outer(x, x))
for i in range(d):
    ans -= np.outer(I[:, i], np.outer(I[:, i], x))
    ans -= np.outer(I[:, i], np.outer(x, I[:, i]))
    ans -= np.outer(x, np.outer(I[:, i], I[:, i]))
```